# Pandas - Setting column value, based on a function that runs on another column

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have been all over the place to try and get this to work (new to datascience). It's obviously because I don't get how the datastructure of Panda fully works.

I have this code:

```py
def getSearchedValue(identifier):
    full_str = anedf["Diskret data"].astype(str)
    value=""
    if full_str.str.find(identifier) <= -1:
        start_index = full_str.str.find(identifier)+len(identifier)+1
        end_index = full_str[start_index:].find("|")+start_index
        value = full_str[start_index:end_index].astype(str)
        return value

for col in anedf.columns:
    if col.count("#") > 0:
        anedf[col] = getSearchedValue(col)
```

What i'm trying to do is iterate over my columns. I have around 260 in my dataframe. If they contain the character #, it should try to fill values based on whats in my "Diskret data" column.
Data in the "Diskret data" column is completely messed up but in the form `CCC#111~VALUE|DDD#222~VALUE|` <- Until there is no more identifiers + values. All identifiers are not present in each row, and they come in no specific order.
The function works if I run it with hard coded strings in regular Python document. But with the dataframe I get various error like:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

    Input In [119], in <cell line: 12>()
        12 for col in anedf.columns:
        13     if col.count("#") > 0:
---> 14         anedf[col] = getSearchedValue(col)

Input In [119], in getSearchedValue(identifier)
        4 full_str = anedf["Diskret data"].astype(str)
        5 value=""
----> 6 if full_str.str.find(identifier) <= -1:
        7     start_index = full_str.str.find(identifier)+len(identifier)+1
        8     end_index = full_str[start_index:].find("|")+start_index
```

I guess this is because it evaluate against all rows (Series) which obviously provides some false and true errors. But how can I make the evaluation and assignment so it it's evaluating+assigning like this:

| Diskret data | CCC#111 | JJSDJ#1234 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CCC#111~1IBBB#2323~2234 | 1 (copied from "Diskret data") | 0 |
| JJSDJ#1234~Heart attack | 0 (or skipped since the row does not contain a value for the identifier) | Heart attack |

The plan is to drop the "Diskret data" when the assignment is done, so I have the data in a more structured way.

--- Update---
By request:

I have included a picture of how I visualize the problem, And what I seemingly can't make it do.

[Problem visualisation](https://i.ibb.co/jf6ZBpN/problem.png)

Comment: Are you able to share some more example rows/columns from your dataframe and/or the original file? I feel like there's probably an easier way to approach this.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't `CCC#111~1IBBB#2323~2234 ` yield two values? This problem seems amenable to regex.

Comment: @CollinCunningham Yes, you are right. It will generate two values, but I would have a column for that value further down the road (I have like 260 or something like that. More than I could write here). Each identifier should have it's own column.

Comment: So for all columns, I would have to look into the same "Diskret data" column to see if there is a value I should copy over. I don't mind the performance. This is only for setting up the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex you could do something like:

```
def map_(list_) -> pd.Series:
    if list_:
        idx, values = zip(*list_)
        return pd.Series(values, idx)
    else:
        return pd.Series(dtype=object)

series = pd.Series(
    ['CCC#111~1|BBB#2323~2234', 'JJSDJ#1234~Heart attack']
)
reg_series = series.str.findall(r'([^~|]+)~([^~|]+)')
reg_series.apply(map_)
```

### Breaking this down:

Create a new series by running a map on each row that turns your long string into a list of tuples

Create a new series by running a map on each row that turns your long string into a list of tuples.

```
reg_series = series.str.findall(r'([^~|]+)~([^~|]+)')
reg_series
# output:
# 0    [(CCC#111, 1), (BBB#2323, 2234)]
# 1        [(JJSDJ#1234, Heart attack)]
```

Then we create a `map_` function. This function takes each row of `reg_series` and maps it to two rows: the first with only the "keys" and the other with only the "values". We then create series of this with the index as the keys and the values as the values.

*Edit:* We added in a `if`/`else` statement that check whether the list exists. If it does not, we return an empty series of type object.

```
def map_(list_) -> pd.Series:
    if list_:
        idx, values = zip(*list_)
        return pd.Series(values, idx)
    else:
        return pd.Series(dtype=object)
...
print(idx, values)  # first row
# output:
# ('CCC#111', 'BBB#2323') (1, 2234)
```

Finally we run `apply` on the series to create a dataframe that takes the outputs from `map_` for each row and zips them together in columnar format.

```
reg_series.apply(map_)

# output: 
#   CCC#111 BBB#2323    JJSDJ#1234
# 0       1     2234           NaN
# 1     NaN      NaN  Heart attack
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I can't really grasp how to copy values over in each feature column. I have now uploaded a picture to help visualize it better.

Comment: I added more information here that should help. Please try it with the sample series and follow-up if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi Collin, I must be very bad at this syntax thing. I got ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) when I ran the reg_series.apply(map_). However I did manage to create the reg_series containing a list of tuples. reg_series = anedf["Diskret data"].str.findall.... I can iterate through the list of touples in the series and set the value by using something like anedf.at[index, tuple_index[0]] = tuple_index[1] in two for loops. But for the sake of your time and the question for others to read, I would like to complete it your neat way. Any idea how to get it done?

Comment: @Jelboen I worry that some of your data may be malformed or empty: when we don't find anything it will return an empty list, which breaks the function. Here we need empty handling. I have updated the answer with a function that does this. Let me know if this works!

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you. I will assign the points :)